# Есть ли ошибка: "Может быть, они неправы?"

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Есть ли ошибка: “Может быть, они неправы?”

Answer (score 1):

Варианты возможны (в частности, существует зависимость от логического ударения):

***Может быть, они непрАвы? Может быть, онИ не правы?***

**Пояснение**

**1) Грамота.ру больше не относит *не прав* к словам, которые всегда пишутся раздельно** (не должен, не обязан и др). Выбор формы написания НЕ делается по общему правилу для прилагательных (утверждение или отрицание).

Вопрос № 301536
Скажи мне, что я не прав, и я скажу, кто ты. Скажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае пишется *не прав* или неправ_. Слитно или раздельно?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: **Предпочтительно слитное написание.**

Вопрос № 302469
 ...у нас фраза "**клиент всегда неправ**" , как правильно писать не? так как на сайте у вас различное написание в ответах,а именно информации по написанию этого слова мы не нашли ((( можно ли писать и так, и так ... какие источники тому доказательство?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Вот что сказано об этом в справочнике Д. Э Розенталя.

Пишутся слитно с частицей не прилагательные, которые в сочетании с этой частицей приобретают противоположное значение (обычно такое слово можно заменить синонимом без не).

В зависимости от смысла частица не с краткими формами прилагательных может писаться то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: наша семья небогата (‘бедна’) — наша семья не богата (‘среднего достатка’); эта девушка некрасива (утверждается отрицательный признак) — эта девушка не красива (отрицается положительный признак); адрес неизвестен (отрицается «известность»); Невелика беда — дождь. — Не велика, казалось бы, эта дистанция для стайеров.

Таким образом, в Вашем случае рекомендуем писать слитно: **Клиент всегда неправ.**

**2) Словарь, в котором указаны формы *неправый и неправ*** с одним значением.

**НЕПРАВЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -прав, -а, -о. 1. Поступающий, говорящий ошибочно, неправильно. Человек, н. в своих действиях. Вы **неправы,** отказавшись подписать заявление. Считать друг друга неправыми. 2. Высок. Несправедливый; противоречащий праву (1.П.; 3 зн.). Н. суд. Н-ое обвинение. * **Неправ** твой, о Небо, святой приговор! (Лермонтов).

3) **В Нацкорпусе** раздельное написание встречается чаще, но и слитное тоже не редкость.  Все зависит от конкретной ситуации. Слово ***неправ*** часто ведет себя как утвердительная форма, образуя сочетания с зависимыми словами:  *теперь ясно, насколько он неправ; в чем-то он неправ, тут он явно неправ, он был неправ.*

Answer (score 0):

Мнения, насчёт слитно-раздельно "не/прав" разошлись, но старая школа категорически настаивает на раздельном написании.

С краткими прилагательными, не имеющими полной формы или имеющими в полной форме другое значение, частица «не» пишется раздельно. Перечислим эти слова:

***[не рад, не горазд, не должен, не склонен, не готов, не прав, не намерен, не согласен.](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/ne-s-prilagatelnyimi.html)***

В предложении они выполняют роль сказуемого или являются его частью.

---

[Другой источник](https://bolcheknig.ru/slovar/byla-daleko-ne-krasavica-dasha-skazala-talantu-i-a-goncharova-o/):

> Раздельно пишется не с притяжательными прилагательными (не кошачья
>   порода, не охотничье ружье), с прилагательными и наречиями в
>   сравнительной степени (не выше, не красивее, не больше, не дольше) и с
>   краткими прилагательными, которые в полной форме или не употребляются,
>   или получают другое значение, или вовсе полной формы не имеют: *не
>   должен, не обязан, не намерен, **не прав**, не виден, не готов, не
>   согласен, не склонен, не рад, не нужно, не надо, не прочь.*

---

Так что ошибка именно здесь: "Может быть, они не правы?"